# NetworkImage does not work to render url

Tags: dart, flutter

I tried to render a image with the `_renderImage` method using a `NetworkImage` but all what shows up is a big red square. When I render with the `_renderImage2` method using `Image.network` it works fine. unfortunatly I need the decorations from and the boder radius of `renderImage`. Why does it not work?

```
  Container _renderImage(GroupMessageController message) => new Container(
      width: 300.0,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(25.0)),
          image: new DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              image: new NetworkImage(message.mediaUrl.toString()))));

  Container _renderImage2(GroupMessageController message) => new Container(
        width: 300.0,
        child: new Image.network(
          message.mediaUrl.toString(),
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
      );

    [√] Flutter (on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.64], locale en-US, channel alpha)
    • Flutter at c:\sdks\flutter
    • Framework revision e8aa40eddd (5 weeks ago), 2017-10-17 15:42:40 -0700
    • Engine revision 7c4142808c
    • Tools Dart version 1.25.0-dev.11.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ride4\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.2)
    • Flutter plugin version 19.1
    • Dart plugin version 172.4343.25

[√] Connected devices
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between using `decoration` property and `Image` widget.

Using `decoration` of `DecoratedBox` is like defining a background image of your box. But since your `DecoratedBox` has no child at all, then it has a default size of 0x0.

On the other hand, `Image` has a different purpose and *will* have a size.

**edit**

```
    return new DecoratedBox(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        image: new DecorationImage(
          image: new NetworkImage("https://displate.com/displates/2017-09-04/7b4f0a94798f5d8c1ea094984c766911_0dc0c70583e9e27897d5c0125acac0c1.jpg?h=357&w=500&v=3"),
        ),
      ),
      child: new SizedBox(
        width: 300.0,
        height: 300.0,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: if I add that to the as a `child: new Container(width: 300.0)` to the outside Container that does not make a difference

Comment: I said `DecoratedBox` not `BoxDecoration`

Comment: than  dont know what you mean - couldu provide a little code snippet please